# Can't start apache when enable php 7 (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: apache2, php7

I want php to work, but when I do `sudo a2enmod php7.0` and then `sudo service apache2 restart` I'll get `Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journactl -xe" for details.`.

My config (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`) looks like this (click the link): http://pastebin.com/1DqKZB9N

The server works without php, so how can I fix this bug?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you fix it? how?